# Can I get the data in v-text-field with a method other than v-model?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

```
<div v-for="i in parseInt(numberquestion)" :key="i">
        <v-layout>
         <v-flex xs6 offset-3  mt-15"  >
          <label for=""> enter the {{index}} question:</label> <v-text-field v- 
model="content"> </v-text-field>
          <label for=""> A Şıkkını Giriniz:</label><v-text-field v-model="optiona" > </v-text- 
field>
          <label for=""> B Şıkkını Giriniz:</label><v-text-field v-model="optionb"> </v-text- 
field>
          <label for=""> C Şıkkını Giriniz:</label><v-text-field v-model="optionb" > </v-text- 
field>
          <label for=""> D Şıkkını Giriniz:</label><v-text-field v-model="optiond" > </v-text- 
field>
            <v-select  :items="options"   filled v-model="selected"   label="Choose correct 
answer"></v-select>
          <v-btn class="btn-right" @click="remove">Remove</v-btn>
          <v-btn class="btn-right mr-3" @click="approve(bla)">Approve</v-btn>
         </v-flex>
        </v-layout>
</div>
```

This code is a question adding panel that works as much as the number of questions. When I enter the number of questions as 3, this panel works three times and when I send the values of the first question with the v-model, the same values are received in the other questions at the same time. How do I get the value in v-text-field for each question separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than v-modeling the same property for each loop of the v-for, you can make it more dynamic.  Rather than doing optiona, optionb, optionc, you could have an object that holds all the v-model results.

```
    <div id="question-container" v-for="question in questions_list">
      <input v-model="question_data[question.id+'_1']">
      <input v-model="question_data[question.id+'_2']">
      <input v-model="question_data[question.id+'_3']">
      <input v-model="question_data[question.id+'_4']">
    </div>
```

Here's a sample:
https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/WNjgRzE